# Is it correct to say that the interval [0,0] is greater than the empty interval (0,0)?

Tags: geometry

3 Questions:

1. Is it correct to say that the interval [0,0] is greater than the empty interval (0,0)?
2. If 1) is true, then it would seem to make sense to say that 0 distance is greater than no distance.  I ask this because it seems like the point that 0 (or any other number) occupies on the real number line actually has a distance greater than no distance.
3. Does [0,0) exist?

Comment: (1.) depends on how you measure it. If you are looking at the number of points, yes; if you are looking at length, no. (2.) "distance" and "size" may not mean the same thing; see part 1. (3.) no

Comment: @jgd1729 [0,0) is just the empty set, so it exists, since empty set does exist.

Comment: @jgd1729 would it be accurate to say that [0,0] has more distance than (0,0)?

Comment: Although this can depend on how you define distance, the formal term refers to a metric space, and in this context the distance between a point and itself is zero.  As mentioned, the notions of distance and size may not be the same depending on how you define size.

Comment: @Divide1918 you are technically correct. The best kind of correct.

Comment: @Studentician it depends on your definition of distance. Using the intuitive definition of continuous distance that we all use on a daily basis, no, a set with a single point and the empty set have the same length. But if we are working in a context where we care more about the number of points in a set, then yes, but this definition of size has its own issues. If we only care about number of points rather than length, then all intervals (a,b) with a<b are the same size since they contain a continuum of points.

Comment: The answer to your deleted question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850259/is-the-union-of-all-of-these-sets-the-set-of-all-natural-numbers is, yes, the union of those sets is the set of all natural numbers.

Answer (score 5):

**Question $\#1$:**

The only meaningful sense that comes to mind in which we can say $[0,0]$ (i.e. $\{0\}$) is bigger than $(0,0)$ (i.e. $\varnothing$) basically amounts to set inclusion, i.e.
$$
A \text{ is bigger than } B \iff B \subseteq A
$$
This isn't necessarily problematic in and of itself, since we like to have ways to compare sets and this one is useful enough in some contexts.

> **EDIT:** I guess you could also say $\{0\}$ is bigger than $\varnothing$, measured by cardinality (i.e. number of elements), but that fails the definition of distance, to be seen in a moment.

---

**Question $\#2$:**

Let's back up a moment. First we need to know what we mean by distance!

In mathematical parlance, "distance" is encoded by the notion of a metric. A metric $d$ on $X$ is a function $d : X \times X \to [0,\infty)$ such that three things hold:

- Symmetry: $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ for all $x,y \in X$
- Positive-Definiteness: $d(x,y) =0 \iff x=y$
- Triangle Inequality: $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z \in X$

Your favorite ways of measuring distance meet these criteria.

> **EDIT:** The "number of elements" idea mentioned earlier doesn't really work as a notion of distance. My best guess for how to interpret this as a distance is defining $d(S,T)$ as, in essence, the difference in their sizes, i.e.
> $$
> d(S,T) := \Big| \#S - \#T \Big|
> $$
> where $\#S$ means "the number of elements in $S$". But even for finite sets this fails the symmetry axiom of distance, since $d(\{0\},\{1\})=0$. I'm not sure of a way to modify this to a notion of a distance that is, in fact, all of (i) a distance, (ii) with cardinality at its heart, and (iii) somewhat noteworthy or useful or at least intuitive.

But now one has to ask: how do you intend to formalize your notion of distance? There is no intuitive idea your post gives me; we can only speak of a distance between two particular things. Another issue is that there is no real notion of "no distance": much like in conversational English, "no distance" and "zero distance" would be interpreted the same way (unless you intend to have a formalization of what "no distance" means).

Perhaps instead what you speak of in terms of distance is "length" of a set. In the reals, this can be formalized, somewhat. But ultimately we conclude that the length of the interval $[a,b]$ is $b-a$ (for $b \ge a$). There are probably several ways you can formalize it, though the ones I'm familiar with would require working with that as an axiomatic assumption. But then you could write the length (or more commonly "measure") of a one-dimensional set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ by, say,
$$
\operatorname{measure}(S)
= \inf_{C(S)} \left\{ \sum_{I_k \in C(S)} \text{measure}(I_k)   \right\}
$$
where the infimum is taken over all $C(S)$, defined to be the collections $\{I_k\}$ of at-most-countably many intervals covering $S$. Bit of a clunky definition to work with, and I'm foregoing some technicalities, but essentially: if you can find a bunch of intervals that cover your set $S$, and the sum of those intervals' lengths is $\ell$, then $S$ has length at most $\ell$ for sure.

Then, for instance, $[0,0]$ definitely has length zero: consider a collection of a single interval, $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Then the length of $[0,0]$ is at most $2\varepsilon$, for every $\varepsilon$. Certainly length can't be negative, though, so taking $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily small it has to be zero.

What about the length of $(0,0)$, i.e. $\varnothing$? Well, if you're familiar with set inclusion laws, $\varnothing \subseteq S$ for every set $S$. So in particular, any collection of intervals is one covering $\varnothing$. So the previous $\varepsilon$-based interval "collection" likewise shows us that $\varnothing$ has length zero as well.

---

**Question $\#3$:**

Recall: given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we define
$$\begin{align*}
[a,b] &:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a \le x \le b \}\\
[a,b) &:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a \le x < b \}\\
(a,b] &:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x \le b \}\\
(a,b) &:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x < b \}
\end{align*}$$

Well, then the set $[0,0)$ consists of all points $x$ such that $0 \le x < 0$. But if such an $x$ existed, then $0<0$, which is nonsensical. So $[0,0)$ exists, as the empty set $\varnothing$, just as $(0,0)$ does.